# JQuery change event on Select not firing IE8 Firefox 4.0.1

Tags: jquery

I know this question was asked before but I have the following simple code which is not working in IE / MOZILLA
This is a simple script where I am trying to sort out a problem I had.
see code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('hi');
        });

        $('.target').change(function () {
            alert('Handler for .change() called.');
        });
    </script>
    Index</h2>
<p>
<form action="/Review" method="post">        <select class="target">
            <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
            <option value="option2">Option 2</option>

        </select>
```

Comment: " not working in IE / MOZILLA" ? is it working in any other browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `.change` binding up into the `$(document).ready()` or it will run before there is anything in the DOM that matches your `.target` selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('hi');
    $('.target').change(function () {
        alert('Handler for .change() called.');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing script like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            alert('hi');
            $('.target').change(function () {
            alert('Handler for .change() called.');
           });
        });
```